# Column is either not in any table in the FROM list

Tags: java, derby

I'm working on a University Recruitment System, and I've connected a derby database to my Netbeans Java project, I'm trying to add Student object into the Student table in the database.. Here's the function I'm using (It works with staff but the object has fixed information not inputs)..

```
public static boolean addStudent(Student s) {
    String connectionURL = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/University";
    try {
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "BUE", "BUE");
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        String sql = "INSERT INTO STUDENT VALUES (" +  s.getFirstName()+ "," + "'" + s.getLastName()+ "'" + "," + "'" +  s.getCountry()+"'"  + "," +"'" +  s.getEmail()+ "'" + "," + "'" + s.getBirthYear() + "'" + "," + "'"+  s.getStudentUsername() + "'" +"," +  s.getStudentPassword() +")";
        System.out.println("@@@");            
        st.executeUpdate(sql);
        st.close();
        return true;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here's the scope of creating the object and calling the addStudent() function..

```
Student newAccount= new Student( firstNameTextField2.getText(), lastNameTextField.getText(), EmailTextField.getText(),  countryTextField.getText(), birthYearTextField.getText(), usernameTextField.getText(), passText);
        Student.addStudent(newAccount);
```

While running and creating a new account (While inserting) it gives me this error..

```
Column 'E' is either not in any table in the FROM list or appears within a join specification and is outside the scope of the join specification or appears in a HAVING clause and is not in the GROUP BY list. If this is a CREATE or ALTER TABLE  statement then 'E' is not a column in the target table.
```

Comment: Well print out the SQL before executing it and see what it looks like. Just adding a few quotes around strings is nowhere near enough to protect yourself from unusual names and SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: Sorry where should I put few quotes?

Comment: I am saying that your existing code that constructs the INSERT statement is not safe. You are just adding quotes around things like `s.getLastName()` - but that won't work if the name itself contains a quote. Look at using `PreparedStatement`. https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: As a more serious link (the XKCD link is funny, though!), read this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html#supply_values_ps